# ObjC doesn't forward scrollViewDidScroll message correctlly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, runtime, message, forwarding

I want to use multicast delegate tech for `UIScrollViewDelegate`. My general idea is similar with this:
https://github.com/tkach/MulticastDelegate/blob/master/MulticastDelegate/MulticastDelegate.m

But I couldn't forwarding the `scrollViewDidScroll` message, I found that I never received this message.
So are there someone encounter or know the reason of this?
thx...

Answer (score 0):

I think the `UIScroll` will cache its delegate for some performance reason. You must **prepare your multicast delegate at first**. Then set the original delegate for `UIScroll`. At last the `UIScroll` will know that you have implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

When you want to change your multicast delegate, remember to reset the original delegate for `UIScroll` like this:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = nil;
self.scrollView.delegate = yourMulticastDelegate;
```